# C - What is the name of a structure

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I'm a beginner and I'm studying the C language.
I have already studied arrays and I know that the name of an array is the address of its first element, while the address of the array corresponds to the entire structure delineated by the array.

Now I'm studying the structures and I would like to understand in this case what exactly corresponds to the name of a structure.
The output result of these instructions:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct numbers
{
       int b;
       int c;
};

int main(void)
{
       struct numbers some_numbers = {1, 0};

       printf("%d\n", some_numbers);
}
```

It is the following:

```
Output: 1
```

While the result in output of these instructions:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct numbers
{
       char a;
       int b;
       int c;
};

int main(void)
{
       struct numbers some_numbers = {0, 0, 0};

       printf("%d\n", some_numbers);
}
```

is the following

```
Output: 7356928
```

Is there any connection between the name of the structure and its first element, as happens with arrays?

The name of a structure should be important, otherwise why do we use the name of a structure as an argument for a function, if we want to pass the structure by value?

Comment: Use structure member for `printf` not the structure start address: `printf( "%d\n", some_numbers.b );`. Try to keep compilation with 0 warnings!

Comment: It's undefined behavior but I think the weird number you see is a problem of padding. If you memset the struct instead of initializing it like this : `{0,0,0}` then 0 is printed.

Comment: @i486 He doesn't print the start address of a structure. He prints (more or less random) parts of the structure.

Comment: You should always enable warnings in your compiler. Add `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic` for GCC. The compiler might not agree to use `%d` and provide a struct for `printf`.

Comment: @Gerhardh OK. I had to write the data at structure start address but have not read the final text.

Comment: @axiac -- `array` and `&array[0]` are the same thing (in most expressions), but `&array` is _not_, since this is a pointer to `array[]`, not a pointer to the first element of `array[]`.

Comment: @DavidBowling you are right. I deleted my previous comment.

Comment: This is a perfect example of why `printf` is such a ridiculously dangerous function :) Think of it as a goat: it eats anything you feed it. How healthy the goat ends up in the end depends on what you feed it, but it will gladly eat anything given to it without protest.

Answer (score 4):

If you pass anything other than an `int` to `printf("%d")` you're invoking **undefined behavior**.

Comment: Not entirely true: non-pointer built-in types narrower than an `int` are widened to an `int`.

Comment: TBH I was waiting for someone to come along and state the corner case so I could steal their verbiage :-) Thanks.

Comment: Ha. Nothing wrong with doing that! as this is a collaborative site after all. Have an upvote. (But my non-pointer bit is speculation; I'm not certain of that.)

Comment: Are we going to do signed/unsigned char extension to int again?  :(

Answer (score 3):

As far as the C standard is concerted, you're invoking [undefined behaivor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because you're passing a struct to `printf` while the `%d` format specifier is expecting an `int`.

That being said, here's what's most likely happening in your particular case.

In the first piece of code, the struct contains an `int` as the first member.  Assuming the entire contents of the struct are pushed onto the stack when `printf` is called, the `%d` format specifier picks up the first member which is an `int` and prints it.

In the second case, you have a `char` for the first member and an `int` for the second member.  Because member are typically aligned on a byte boundary that this a multiple of the member size, additional padding is inserted.  With the implicit padding, struct probably looks something like this, assuming a 4 byte `int`:

```
struct numbers
{
       char a;
       char padding[3];
       int b;
       int c;
};
```

When you initialize this struct, each member is filled but the contents of the padding is indeterminate.

When the struct is then passed to `printf` (assuming the entire struct is pushed on the stack), the `%d` format specifier reads the first 4 bytes as an `int`.  This is comprised of the field `a` which is a `char`, plus the 3 padding bytes.  The output you're seeing reflects the indeterminate values in those padding bytes.

But to reiterate, this is undefined behavior.  Using a different compiler or compiling with different optimization settings can change how undefined behavior will manifest.

Answer (score 2):

Array designators used in expressions with rare exceptions are converted to pointers to their first elements.

So when you for example pass an array to a function then in fact you pass a pointer to the first element of the array.

As for structure then there is no such implicit conversion. When you pass a structure to a function then a whole structure object is passed.

Take into account that structure address and the address of the first data member of structure are coincided.

Thus in this call

```
printf("%d\n", some_numbers);
```

the function printf interprets the memory passed to the function as a memory occupied by an object of the type int and indeed in the first program the initial portion of the memory is occupied by the first data member of the struture that has the type `int`.

In the second case the first data member of the structure that has the type char is padded by bytes to align the structure at least to the alignment of the type int.

In this initialization

```
struct numbers some_numbers = {0, 0, 0};
```

only one byte of the memory allocated to the first member of the structure was initialized. The padding bytes have indeterminate values.

As result the corresponding call of the function printf has unpredictable and undefined behaviour.

In general the both programs do not make sense and have undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Array and structure and totally different in scenario. structure is a user define type but not array. Both have their own access mechanism. Inside structure you can declare end number of different variable including object of an another structure.

What you are doing in your example (in C) is not correct at all. But same you can do in C++ with the help of operator overloading.

Answer (score 0):

Inside printf(), you use format specifiers like %d or %s or so on. The only issue is: the specifier should match the data passed as a next parameter(s).

So, once you put inconsistent pair of specifier and data, you should receive anything, and most of them could be garbage due incompatible memory layouts for different data types.